# Таймер на выбор действия

Tags: python

Скажу сразу, у меня Windows 10 и Python 3.9, если эта информация вдруг понадобится.

Я никогда не сталкивалась с подобной задачей и использованием времени в программе, потому будет очень здорово, если на вопрос будет ответ, который можно будет доступно понять.

Мне хотелось бы, чтобы было установлено опрелённое время, которое довалось бы человеку на выбор нужного варианта ответа. Но. Нужен таймер, который в режиме реального времени будет отсчитывать время, чтобы человек мог его контролировать (максимум 10 секунд).

```
f = None
while f not in ['1' , '2']:
    f = input ("""Хотите взять предмет с собой?
1. Да. 
2. Нет. """)
    if f == '1':
        print ("Хороший выбор.")
    elif f == '2':
        print ("Очень зря.")
    else: 
        print ("Такого варианта ответа нет,ответьте на вопрос ещё раз.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вот коротко, кроссплатфоменно, без внешних библиотек:

```
import threading
import signal

class Timeout(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.done = threading.Lock()
        self.main_id = threading.get_ident()
        super().__init__()
        
    def run(self):
        ok = self.done.acquire(blocking=True, timeout=self.timeout)
        if not ok:
            signal.pthread_kill(self.main_id, signal.SIGINT)
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.done.acquire()
        self.start()
        return self
        
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.done.release()
        return True
        

with Timeout(2):
    try:
        input('введите за 2 сек:')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('не успел')
    else:
        print('успел')
```

Тут таймаут вынесен в контекст менеджер, чтоб основной код не засорять. `pthread_kill` наверное единственный метод прервать стандартный `input()` - кто знает другие?

Comment: А возможно в этом коде сделать так, чтобы было видно сам таймер и время, которое осталось?

Comment: @Daria этим способом сложно так сделать. Нужен уже другой режим терминала

Answer (score 3):

Если под Windows, то можно привлечь msvcrt читать посимвольно в отдельном потоке. Хотя... В данном случае тут потоки даже не нужны.

```py
import msvcrt, sys, time

def timed_input(text, string_mode=True, default=None, timeout=5):
    def flushed_output(out_text):
        sys.stdout.write(out_text)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    
    flushed_output(text)
    result = default
    input_text = ""
    if not string_mode:
        last_timeout = timeout
        time_text = str(timeout)
        time_text_len = len(time_text)
        flushed_output(f"[{time_text:>{time_text_len}}] ")
    time_start = time.time()
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            chr = msvcrt.getwch()
            flushed_output(chr)
            if string_mode:
                if ord(chr) == 13:
                    break
                input_text += chr
            else:
                input_text = chr
                break
        time.sleep(0.05)
        dt = int(time.time() - time_start)
        if not string_mode:
            if timeout - dt < last_timeout:
                last_timeout = timeout - dt
                flushed_output("\b"*(time_text_len+3)+f"[{last_timeout:>{time_text_len}}] ")
        if dt >= timeout:
            break

    if len(input_text) > 0:
        result = input_text
    flushed_output("\n")
    return result


name = timed_input("Введите ваше имя за 5 секунд: ", default="Иванушка-дурачок", timeout=5)
print("Добро пожаловать,", name)
f = None
while f not in ['1' , '2']:
    f = timed_input ("""Хотите взять предмет с собой?
  1. Да. 
  2. Нет.
Ваш выбор? """, string_mode=False, timeout=10)
    if f == '1':
        print ("Хороший выбор.")
    elif f == '2':
        print ("Очень зря.")
    elif not f:
        print ("Вы так и не определились, попробуйте снова.")
    else: 
        print ("Такого варианта ответа нет, ответьте на вопрос ещё раз.")
```

Comment: А на линуксе просто прерывание по сигалярм через трай)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, msvcrt - это библиотека или модуль? Просто впервые встречаюсь с ним и пытаюсь понять, нужно ли это скачивать (как библиотеку) , потому что просто как код не запускается.

Comment: @eri На линуксе ещё через `select([sys.stdin])` можно. Там вообще куча вариантов.

Comment: @Daria А вот честно, я без понятия. У меня оно уже было. Судя по всему это стандартный  модуль и уже идёт в комплекте с питоном (под Windows только), т.к. [документация по нему](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html) является частью питоновской документации. В 3.7.4 под Win7 он у меня есть, в 3.9.0 под Win10 - тоже.

Comment: @Daria делайте кроссплатфоменно на тредах